# Symfony 4.2 override translation bundle doesn't work

Tags: symfony, translation, fosuserbundle

Symfony 4.2 documentation :
"
For example, to override the translations defined in the Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.es.yml file of the FOSUserBundle, create a`<your-project>/translations/FOSUserBundle.es.yml` file.
"

That's doesn't work for me and i clean my cache ! Any one have some idea ?
Symfony take always the FOSUserBundle.es.yml of vendor.

Comment: Symfony 4.2 does not use the `Resources` folder anymore; translations are now at the root of the project, in a `translations` folder. Did you check that you were viewing the correct version of the documentation ?

Comment: it's ok just cache:clear is not enough. I have deleted cache directory and that's work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder in `/translations/FOSUserBundle/`, move the translations you need and redo it.

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.1"
"symfony": "require": "4.2.*"
```